# How to get email of a Facebook friend in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am developing an iPhone application that will send email to a logged in user's friends. I am using Facebook Connect for the same. The problem is that I am getting the uid of all friends but what is the way to send email to these uids (friends' UIDs).
Also I'm not able to get the email id of any of the Facebook friends. Can I get the emails of the users' Facebook friends in my iPhone App?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get email of friends. Although you can send an email to `uid`s provided they have granted permission to you app.

> A comma-separated list of recipient user IDs. The recipients must be people who have already authorized your application. You can email up to 100 people at a time.

Beyond [`general information`](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=16374) you are require [`extended permissions`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) which requires authentication (which you are using). Any `extended permission` works only with the `user` who has granted it to. So your app's `user`'s `friends` will have to grant the permission to email before you can send them one. In other words, you can send a [notification email](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notifications.sendEmail) to those `friend`s of your `user` who have added your app and have granted you the permission to email. Facebook has [this page](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Communicating_with_Users_via_Email) on communicating via email.

Comment: Thank u very much Ashish,
      It would be very helpful if u kindly provide me some code about how to do this....

Comment: And `this` is? You may want to follow one of the links in my answer for documented examples.